# How to set the OpenAI endpoint `OPENAI_API_BASE` for the Chat Notebook?

Tags: chatai, llm

I have an OpenAI Key associated with a specific OpenAI API Base, such as `https://openaiXXX.cloud/v1`, instead of the default base `https://api.openai.com/v1`. This key enables me to run it successfully.

```shell
curl $OPENAI_API_BASE/models \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
      -H "OpenAI-Organization: org-mvUSw9fFhNVVqQUesafVo0F6"
```

I only find how to set OpenAI Key `SystemCredential["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the API endpoint from https://api.openai.com/v1 to https://openaiXXX.cloud/v1

For example

Before
curl [https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions\](https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions%5C)
-H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" 
-H "OpenAI-Organization: org-mvUSw9fFhNVVqQUesafVo0F6"

After
https://openaiXXX.cloud/v1/chat/completions
-H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" 
-H "OpenAI-Organization: org-mvUSw9fFhNVVqQUesafVo0F6"